# What does UMA refer in Chrome?

Tags: chromium

I saw related words like 'UMA opt-in users' when I browse code of chromium. Can anyone help me understanding 'UMA' or 'safebrowsing'?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

UMA (User Metrics Analysis) is user metrics that are reported to help make Chrome/Chromium better. e.g. latency metrics, [HTML/CSS feature usage](https://www.chromestatus.com/metrics/css/popularity), etc. These are the bits that are sent back to Google when you check the "Help make Google Chrome better by automatically sending usage statistics..." box on installation.

Safe browsing is the feature of chrome that checks page loads for phishing and malware. More info [here](https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/safebrowsing)

Comment: Hi, thank you for answering. What's the full name of UMA?

Comment: UMA = User Metrics Analysis