# In computing, what does UMA mean?

Tags: hardware, terminology, hardware-acceleration

I tried to figure out what UXA meant so I read on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UMA_Acceleration_Architecture):

> In computing, UMA Acceleration Architecture (UXA) is the reimplementation of the EXA graphics acceleration architecture of the X.Org Server developed by Intel.

Except now I don't know what UMA means. What does UMA mean?

It seems related to SNA Sandybridge's New Acceleration which is related to GPU graphics processing unit, which is related to graphics cards, which are video cards, which is related to kernel modules which seem like another way to say video drivers.

I read on [What does UMA refer in Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39009581/what-does-uma-refer-in-chrome) that it means user metrics analysis but I think that question is in a different context.

The fact that there is the word architecture in the acronym UXA makes me think that UMA might be some sort of vendor so maybe "UMA Acceleration Architecture" means "some vendor's particular grouping of hardware and software for graphics processing". But I'm not sure.